# Receiving error in RSpec for PUT, but not POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rspec

In my specs, when I run the POST request below, everything works fine.

```
    before do
      request_payload = {
        player: {
          first_name: "Joe",
          last_name: "Carradine",
          team_id: "1"
        }
      }

      post :create, request_payload
    end
```

But when I run a spec for PUT:

```
    before do
      request_payload = {
        player: {
          first_name: "Buck",
          last_name: "Carradine",
          team_id: "1"
        }
      }

      put :update, id: 3, request_payload
    end
```

I get an error like this:

```
[filename]_spec.rb:139: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError)

[filename]_spec.rb:198: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

Any ideas? Is there a different syntax for PUT I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the syntax error, use `put :update, { id: 3 }, request_payload`, not `put :update, id: 3, request_payload`.  Ruby only supports "bare" (e.g. curly-braceless) hashes as the last argument to the method, so `id: 3` cannot appear in the middle of an argument list without being wrapped in curly braces.