# Receiving undefined method error in Rspec PUT Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, rspec, tdd

In my specs, when I run the POST request below, everything works fine.

```
    before do
      request_payload = {
        player: {
          first_name: "Joe",
          last_name: "Carradine",
          team_id: "1"
        }
      }

      post :create, request_payload
    end
```

But when I run a spec for PUT:

```
    before do
      request_payload = {
        player: {
          first_name: "Buck",
          last_name: "Carradine",
          team_id: "1"
        }
      }

      put :update, { id: 3 }, request_payload
    end
```

I get an error like this:

```
 Failure/Error: put :update, { id: 1 }, request_payload
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I can't figure out what is being considered nil. This API call works fine in a REST client.

This is another error based on a previous SO question: [Receiving error in RSpec for PUT, but not POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024146/receiving-error-in-rspec-for-put-but-not-post)

Comment: what if you do: `put :update, { id: 3 }.merge(request_payload)`

Comment: That worked (thank you, can you add as an answer?), but given the id hash represents a value from the URL and not from the payload, is this technique a good test?

Comment: Actually, every single data passed through a form is available through params so you don't cheat there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do :

```
put :update, { id: 3 }.merge(request_payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing like so:

```
describe 'PUT #update' do

before do

  @todo = FactoryGirl.create(:todo)

  @initial_title = @todo.title
  @initial_updated_at = @todo.updated_at
  @new_title = 'Title Changed'

  request_payload = { :title => @new_title }

  put :update, :id => @todo.id, :todo => request_payload, :format => :json

  @todo.reload

end

it 'should retrieve status code of 204' do
  response.status.should eq(204)
end

it 'updated attributes should not be as initially' do
  @todo.title.should_not eq(@initial_title)
  @todo.updated_at.should_not eq(@initial_updated_at)
end

it 'updated attribute should be the the same' do
  @todo.title.should eq(@new_title)
end

it 'updated date should be increased' do
  @todo.updated_at.should > @initial_updated_at
end


end
```

May be useful additionally for somebody, the way of doing similar tests;)